# What executes a process & threads spawning processes

Tags: c, multithreading, process, system

I would need some clarifications regarding processes and threads.
I learned recently that all threads (user-level or kernel-level) are executed by a kernel, i.e. they are mapped to a kernel-thread. 
I also learned that process can spawn other processes and threads, but can threads spawn other processes ?

I had a second question, kernel-threads executes threads, but what executes processes ? is a process also mapped to a kernel thread ?

Comment: by kernel-level thread I mean  OS-level thread, a one-to-one thread

Comment: I deleted some parts of the question that might be confusing

Comment: Processes don't get executed, threads do. So nothing executes processes. And "can threads spawn processes?" makes as much sense as "can functions spawn processes?" - all code runs in a thread, so of course?

Comment: Ok, then it's clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the question: * but can threads spawn other processes ? *

The answer is 'yes'.

To do so, in C, call the `fork()` function or any of the `exec*()` functions

although to be perfectly honest, the exec() functions actually replace the current process rather than starting a new process

Comment: Note: there is an "edit" link below your answer.  You do not need to post an altogether new one to make changes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I was stepping back through the list of web pages and (in a moment of confusion) thought that I had not clicked the `post answer` button, so I clicked it.   This resulted in two answer posts,  I deleted the other answer as soon as I realized the error I had made.